# Machine keys in Azure WEBSITES (not webroles)

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

How can I set the machine keys in Azure Websites? I have a solution with hundreds of thousands of sub domains using the same web app. I want to move parts of the app to Azure on the busy subdomains but didn't see a way to do this for "Websites" but I did see something for WebRole but I no likee WebRoles.

Comment: Have to say that Azure Websites "Preview" is exactly that. I moved some of my domains over and the code worked on and off. It runs like a charm on my GoGrid VMs but "Websites" is unpredictable even running its own native code base (ASP.NET). I saw similar behavior when running node.js on Nodjitsu working great and then trying the same on "Websites" and it being sketchy. I worked as a contractor at Microsoft for a time long time back. I want to root for Microsoft but seriously, WTF? Get your shi* together MS. The SQL Server Azure seems to work very well though so can't complain on that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your objective is to setup machine keys with Windows Azure Websites, you can set the  element in the web.config file for the site.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <machineKey 
            decryptionKey="Key_Decryption,IsolateApps" 
            validationKey="Key_Validation,IsolateApps" 
    />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Also if you are using inproc session state with multiple instances, the best option would be to use [Windows Azure Shared Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh697522.aspx) to store session specific data.

Comment: so have you tested this to work with Windows Azure Websites? If so up vote + check mark, sir.

Comment: I'll test it soon. If it works, I'll up vote you and check you off.

Comment: OK. It worked without incident. Thanks! However, stupid azure websites flopped over like a toy when I put my code on it, was on and off again. I'm very disappointed in it and this never happens on my servers. Its a kids toy for now but a nice shiny one like a polished terd. Back to VMs on GoGrid. Microsoft better get its shi_ together.